# How do I send a "test message" with a Garmin InReach Mini 2?

Tags: communication, satellite-phones

I have successfully done a device test on my Garmin InReach Mini 2, but my plan on Garmin Explore states I have sent 0 out of 5 test messages in my plan.  How do I send one of those?  I couldn't find this information in [the manual](https://www8.garmin.com/manuals/webhelp/GUID-802DEF62-EBB2-463C-8C51-C58FB29F89E3/EN-US/inReach_Mini_2_OM_EN-US.pdf).

[image: screenshot of Garmin Explore website showing Current Monthly Usage with 5 Test Messages remaining, 0 used.]
Screenshot of Garmin Explore website.  *Source: Garmin*.

Answer (score 5):

You can read how to test all their devices on [their website](https://support.garmin.com/en-US/?faq=HX8hA43Ys40k1akYC5tAsA).

For your Mini 2 specifically:

> 1. Power on the inReach.
> 2. Press **OK**.
> 3. Select **Service Plan**.
> 4. Select **Test Service**.
> 5. Press **OK**.
> 6. Press **OK** again to begin the test.
>
> Wait while the device sends a test message. When you receive a confirmation message, your device is ready to use.

It is also on page 6 of the manual you linked under "Testing the Device"

After sending a test message and receiving an automated response you should see it show up on the monthly usage.
[image: usage]

Comment: I have explicitly stated in the question (first line) that this is **not** what I'm looking for.  I've already done a device test, but in my plan I still have used 0 out of 5 **test messages**.

Comment: My answer is exactly what you asked for. This is sending a test message (It even says test message in the quoted text). When I send one on my InReach it counts as one of my 5. Perhaps your billing cycle just rolled over between you sending the test and you checking usage? Or maybe your test message didn't fully send. Did you get the automated response? There might also be a 2nd problem you are also facing, but this is definitely how to send a test message.